# Keep getting crash on iOS 9.3 during app launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I included these 3 Screenshots to show what errors I'm having. Pretty much I'm new to app development and this is my first app. On iOS 11 it works fine but on iOS 9.3 thru iOS 10.3 it crashes on the launch screen. I've done just about everything I can find to do online but had no luck. Someone please help. I am running Xcode 9 / Swift 4. THANKS

The second line is giving me the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error

```
@UIApplicationMain 

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


 var window: UIWindow?
 var stationsViewController: StationsViewController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // MPNowPlayingInfoCenter
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    // Make status bar white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black

    // FRadioPlayer config
    FRadioPlayer.shared.artworkSize = 600

    // Get weak ref of StationsViewController
    if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        stationsViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? StationsViewController

    let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]

    // Replace 'YOUR_APP_ID' with your OneSignal App ID.
    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                    appId: "224ba355-0ceb-4d89-9759-46c61a62c7c1",
                                    handleNotificationAction: nil,
                                    settings: onesignalInitSettings)

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;

    // Recommend moving the below line to prompt for push after informing the user about
    //   how your app will use them.
    OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
        print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
    })

    // Sync hashed email if you have a login system or collect it.
    //   Will be used to reach the user at the most optimal time of day.
    // OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(userEmail)

    }
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.


}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

    UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

}

// MARK: - Remote Controls

override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
   super.remoteControlReceived(with: event)

    guard let event = event, event.type == UIEventType.remoteControl else { return }

    switch event.subtype {
    case .remoteControlPlay:
        FRadioPlayer.shared.play()
    case .remoteControlPause:
        FRadioPlayer.shared.pause()
    case .remoteControlTogglePlayPause:
        FRadioPlayer.shared.togglePlaying()
    case .remoteControlNextTrack:
        stationsViewController?.didPressNextButton()
    case .remoteControlPreviousTrack:
        stationsViewController?.didPressPreviousButton()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

[Error Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZVU1.png)

[Error Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UttRC.png)

[Error Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96mXz.png)

Comment: Post text, not pictures.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new here.

Comment: That's fine. Just [edit] your question. Pictures can't be searched or reference and are harder to read. Text is always much better.

Comment: [Edit] your question. Do not post comments.

Comment: Got it, sorry about that.

Comment: Find UICTFont reference view and take a look where you didn't connect reference from storyboard/your nib interface.

Comment: Not having luck finding UICTFont reference view. Noob here

Comment: Looks like private API of Foundation :D https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UICTFont.h Okay so there is some problem with the storyboard/nib initialiisation I guess...

Comment: Easy fix, just go into storyboard `source code` and remove the old incorrect nibs from your viewController.

Comment: No luck finding old NIBs, super noob here.